# How to get current TensorFlow name scope

Tags: tensorflow

I create relative name scopes with `tf.name_scope`.

How can I get the current absolute name scope?

From the code, it looks like `tf.get_default_graph()._name_stack` would give me that but that looks like a non-official way. Is there any official way? (I think not, thus I made an [upstream feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6010).)

(I implemented a bunch of functions like `get_current_name_scope()` or `reuse_name_scope()` [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/TFUtil.py). Note that you need to be careful when mixing `tf.name_scope` and `tf.variable_scope`.)

Comment: did you ever manage to figure out how to do it without having access to the context manager? Or is that impossible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although [golmschenk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446071/1782792) is perfectly correct, taking a look at how [`tf.contrib.framework.get_name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/get_name_scope) is implemented one can see that the current name scope is available in the method [`get_name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_name_scope) of `tf.Graph`:

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_name_scope()
```

Or, for any graph in general:

```
my_graph.get_name_scope()
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently (2017-06-08) in master and in r1.2 is [`tf.contrib.framework.get_name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/get_name_scope).

Comment: Ah, good to know. I just checked the code, it's also a function of the current graph, and it just returns `self._name_stack`.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("foo"):
    with tf.name_scope("bar") as absolute:
        print(absolute)
```

Output:

```
foo/bar/
```

EDIT:

Without access to the enclosing context manager I don't know of a specific function to access the current name scope. With a small detour it's possible as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("foo"):
    with tf.name_scope("bar") as absolute:
        print(tf.no_op(name='.').name[:-1])
```

---

[Relevant Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.name_scope)

Comment: That assumes that I have access to `absolute`. But I'm asking, if I don't know `absolute`, how can I get it?

Comment: So, your answer is basically `tf.no_op(name='.').name[:-1]`. Is that really the best way? Is that better than `tf.get_default_graph()._name_stack`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a better way. That does not mean that there is no better way. However, I'm confident that it is better than using _name_stack since it only relies on the exposed API. That being said I would recommend refactoring your code to be able to use the first idea (context manager) as this seems to be the way tensorflows API was intended to be used.

Comment: you need to do `absolute.name`, just `absolute` doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Did not check but what about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope ? Suggests that `absolute` should suffice or not?