# How do I get the device an Op will be, or is, placed under?

Tags: tensorflow, device

This question is similar to: [How to get current TensorFlow name scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907769/how-to-get-current-tensorflow-name-scope)

But this questions is about the Device scope. I understand it's slightly more complicated, as the device might not have been explicitly scoped, and no guarantees might be given.

Is there *any* way to get insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following utility

```
class _DeviceCaptureOp(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.device = None
  def _set_device(self, device):
    self.device = device

def get_current_device():
  """Returns device string of current graph context."""

  g = tf.get_default_graph()
  op = _DeviceCaptureOp()
  g._apply_device_functions(op)
  return op.device
```

Comment: Note that this just gets device string that is sent to the runtime. The runtime can ignore it in `simple_placer.cc` (ie, to satisfy colocation constraints, or if kernel not available with soft device placement)

Comment: Wow that's a pretty smart tool there, Yaroslav. Thank mate. Understood.